# Is it possible to override console logs

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console.log

If I receive an error from a framework or an error from the browser. Basically a runtime error of any kind. Without modifying the framework, is it possible for me to override the console logs that these frameworks make and the browser's errors. I want to use my own framework with own error handling system when informing the user of errors of practically anything runtime (not syntax errors). I don't know if you would class it all as runtime errors because of the way javascript is executed in the browser but hopefully you will get me?

Is this possible if all the frameworks are written in Javascript?

How is this achieved?

What considerations do I have to make between different browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try overriding the `console.log()` function.

```
//Save original reference
var originalConsole = console;
//Override
console = {};
console.log = function()
{
    //According to MDN the console.log function can receive a variable number of params
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
    {
        //Make your changes here, then call the original console.log function
        originalConsole.log("Change something: "+arguments[i]);
    }
    //Or maybe do something here after parsing all the arguments
    //...
}

console.log("one", "two");
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/crJsL/).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a [`try-catch` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

```
try {
    alert(foo);
} catch(e) {
    alert('The code got the following error: '+e.message);
}
```

Whenever the code between the `try {}` receives an error, the `catch(e) {}` block will execute, with the argument `e` being the error object for the error that occurred. In this case, the variable `foo` is not defined, so executing this code will result in an alert message saying "*The code got the following error: foo is not defined*"

Answer (score 1):

While not over-riding `console.log`, you may be achieve the same effect by overriding `window.onerror`.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror)

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    // Log the error here -- perhaps using an AJAX call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the console logs by creating a "console" object and overriding it's .log() function:

```
var console = {};
console.log = function(){};
```

Some browsers require this to be added to the window object directly; so, for browser compatibility, also add:

```
window.console = console;
```

Additionally, you can override other console functions (e.g. console.info, console.warn and console.error) if you're using those too.

Also, consider reading [this blog post](http://udidu.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/override-console-functions.html) from Udi Talias on overriding the console functions. Good and quick read!

Answer (score 0):

You can custom your console.log here

```
// copy the original
let originalConsole = Object.assign({}, console);
// do something with your log.
            console.log = (value) => {
                //some cool condition
                if (true) {
                    value = "new_log : " + value
                }
                originalConsole.log(value);
            };
```